# SQL Update Manager ID in the Employee Table

Tags: sql-server

I have Employee Temp Table with the following table structure:

```
**|EmpId | EmpName | ManagerId | ManagerName|**
  |------|---------|-----------|------------|
  |[113] |[Test]   |           |[A]         |
  |[111] |[A]      |           |[B]         |
```

I need an update query to populate the Manager Id in the employee temp table by getting the values from the EmpId of the same

```
update B
set B.ManagerCode=A.EmpID 
from EmployeeTemp A INNER JOIN EmployeeTemp B
ON A.ManagerName=B.EmpName
```

This query doesn't work for me. Could anyone suggest a modification to this.

Comment: Do you get an error message or is it that zero rows are updated? In your table you have `ManagerId` but in your `UPDATE` statement you use `ManagerCode` - is this a typo or the cause of your problem?

Comment: I don't get any error message. Wrong values are getting inserted into the ManagerID field.

Comment: if the is correct as you expected make at is Accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is updated successfully

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    EmpId  INT, 
    EmpName VARCHAR(100), 
    ManagerId INT,
    ManagerName VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Table  
SELECT 113 ,'Test', NULL, 'A' UNION ALL         
SELECT 111 ,'A'   , NULL, 'B'        

SELECT * FROM @Table

UPDATE I
SET ManagerId = O.EmpId
FROM @Table I
INNER JOIN @Table o
ON I.ManagerName = o.EmpName

SELECT * FROM @Table
```

Comment: It worked fine now. I don't know what was the issue before. I think I tried to execute the update query while the select query was already running due to which there was a conflict.Thanks for the help.